# Returning generics and collections from subclass methods

Tags: java, generics, collections, subclass

After years of programming in Java I still don't understand this!

The top level class is defined

```
public abstract class GenericCache<K, T, P> {
  public ArrayList<T> getAll() {}
  public T getSafe(K a_id) {}
}
```

The subclass is

```
public class SKUTypeCache<T extends SKUType, P> extends GenericCache<Integer, T, P> {
}
```

When I try to use it

```
SKUTypeCache l_cache = getTheCache();
for (SKUType t : l_cache.getAll()) {
}
```

I get the compile error: "incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to SKUType" on the for loop. Why? I have a similar issue using getSafe().

Comment: What is `P` doing? It seems irrelevant.

Comment: P is used in other subclasses of GenericCache, just not this one.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a generic parameter of `GenericCache` or `SKUTypeCache`. Do you agree that your question is a duplicate?

Comment: `l_cache`  is declared as a raw type (`SKUTypeCache`). If you want that `for` loop to work, `l_cache` must be declared as something like `SKUTypeCache<SKUType>` (or whatever type `getTheCache()` is returning).

Comment: The Raw Type article isn't exactly a duplicate, but it helped me understand what was going on. I changed it to
SKUTypeCache<? extends SKUType, ?> l_cache = getTheCache();
and it works fine now.